# How to remove some html tags from a web page(aspx page) before rendering in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to remove some html tags from the web page (aspx page) in asp.net before it is being rendered. During debugging it shows that the tags removed but when the page gets loaded then the tags are generated again. How can I remove the tags ?

Here is the code I am using:-

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var regex = new Regex("<!--SCRIPT[\\s\\S]*?REMOVE-->[\\s\\S]*?REMOVE-->", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(Server.MapPath("default.aspx"));
        string output = regex.Replace(htmlCode, "");              
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove tags that you are generating or that are already present on the page? Different approaches are possible depending on exactly what you are trying to do. Please provide some code.

Comment: I am trying to remove tags that are generating during run time. I am overriding the render event and writing my code there and during debugging it shows that the tags removed but when the page gets loaded  then the tags are generated again !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String result = Regex.Replace(htmlDocument, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Or  Try this

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^'"">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

[Source](http://haacked.com/archive/2005/04/22/Matching_HTML_With_Regex.aspx/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is that during debugging it shows that the tags removed but when the page gets loaded then the tags are generated again !